# Create links for custom field query

Tags: wordpress

All my post has a custom field `created_by_alias`, I am basically use the value in place of whereever author is used. I have customized the entry-meta function to display this value in plain text, I have also learned to build a query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('meta_key' => 'created_by_alias',
                         'meta_value' => 'somevalue' ));
```

Now for the final part: how to create a link for this piece of text, that brings a listing of all posts by this alias?

Do I need to write a template file or is there a quick way to reuse whatever code that generates links to a category, tag listing?

Comment: What does the query you wrote? Give us an output example because I don't understand what the problems is exactly.

Comment: Did you want something like:                                       `<?php query_posts('meta_key=created_by_alias&meta_value=somevalue');  ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : echo get_permalink(); ?>`
`

Comment: The above should get you a list of permalinks for those posts, if all works correctly. Obviously I had no way to test.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for but seems to me that you want to show a link for the author posts in a specific page, if so, then you can use (using your query)

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('meta_key'=>'created_by_alias', 'meta_value'=>'somevalue' ));
```

If `$query` returns result and you have the `id` then you can use

```
echo get_author_posts_url( $query->posts[0]->ID ); // the `ID` from first row
```

Or for multiple rows, you can loop like

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_ID() ) . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Once this link is clicked, then posts will be retrieved and will be shown according to your page hierarchy, if no author template was found then finally the `inedx.php` will be used.

Also, if you need a custom template and want to query

```
$posts = get_posts(array($ID);
```

Now, to get the id you an use

```
get_user_by( $field, $value ); //  'id', 'slug', 'email', or 'login'
```

So, if you have the `login name` of the user, for example `admin` then you can use

```
$id = get_user_by( 'login', 'admin' )->ID; // php 5+
// or 
$user = get_user_by( 'login', 'admin' );
$id = $user->ID;
```

Then get the link and echo it, whereever you want

```
echo get_author_posts_url( $id );
```